# A Good Alternative for Gmail Offline?

Tags: offline, cross-platform, email-client, gmail

Now that Google has announced [it will be deprecating Chrome apps](http://www.omgchrome.com/not-joke-google-killing-chrome-apps/) for non–Chrome OS devices, I am left trying to find an alternative for one of my favorite email clients: [Gmail Offline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-offline/ejidjjhkpiempkbhmpbfngldlkglhimk?hl=en).

Is/are there are good alternative(s) for email clients? What I'm looking for is one that

- Is obviously compatible with Gmail (I know most are, but still...)
- Has a modern, sleek interface (so Mozilla Thunderbird isn't an option...)
- Is actively supported (so Opera Mail isn't an option...)
- Is cross-platform (so Windows 10's Mail app isn't an option...)
- Has to be fully offline-capable (so, yes, just going to Gmail in my browser is clearly not an option)
- Preferably not super-complex (Thunderbird), though Outlook-level complexity is okay as a maximum. Think Gmail Offline–level complexity...

I'm currently using Windows 10's Mail app, though as stated in the 4<sup>th</sup> point, this is not a preferred option, but rather more or less just a stop-gap until I find a better alternative.

Also, I'm well-aware there may not even be an alternative currently that fits the points listed above; but it doesn't hurt to ask...

(**Note**: I know Chrome apps should still work until 2018, but I see no point in continuing to invest my energies and attention in a product that I'll eventually have to give up anyway. So I feel like getting used to it sooner rather than later is a better plan than just delaying the inevitable & having to deal with the dread of it going away being in the back of my head for the next 2 years.)

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest taking a look at [MailPile](https://www.mailpile.is) - it is early days yet but looks promising.

- Free, Gratis & Completely Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Is obviously compatible with Gmail (I know most are, but still...) **Yes**
- Has a modern, sleek interface (so Mozilla Thunderbird isn't an option...) **Improving all of the time, browser based & you can potentially help to improve it.**
- Is actively supported (so Opera Mail isn't an option...) **In very active developemt**
- Is cross-platform (so Windows 10's Mail app isn't an option...) **Written in Python it runs on platforms from RaspberryPy, through Windows 10/OS-X/Linux and up**
- Has to be fully offline-capable (so, yes, just going to Gmail in my browser is clearly not an option) **Very Much So - a core part of the idea is to download your mails and optionally delete them from the server then browse offline**
- Preferably not super-complex (Thunderbird), though Outlook-level complexity is okay as a maximum. Think Gmail Offline–level complexity... **I personally think that the user interface is nice and simple and the setup, configuration, etc. is very usable.**

Currently MailPile is in a beta state but hopefully by 2018 it will be a lot more mature.

Comment: I'd prefer something a good bit more mature in its development cycle than this, but this seems interesting and I'll be sure to keep it in mind! Thanks! :D